# Doctrine2 - How to select only array elements that meet the criteria in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, database

I'm trying to make a projection for only certain array elements that meets a certain criteria, But what i get returned is the whole document.

Here's what i'm trying to do: I want to select every **category** with its corresponding *embedded* **jobs** that only ACTIVATED and NOT EXPIRED.

Here's what i tried so far :

```
$qb->field('jobs')->exists(true)
        ->expr()->elemMatch($qb->field('jobs.expires_at')->gt(new \DateTime())->field('jobs.is_activated')->equals(false));
```

Which results to:

```
db.categories.find({ "jobs": { "$exists": true }, "jobs.expires_at": { "$gt": new ISODate("2013-11-09T20:47:54+02:00") }, "jobs.is_activated": false }).limit(10).skip().sort([ ]);
```

But what i actually want is:

```
db.categories.find({$exists:{"jobs":true}}, {"name":1, "slug":1, "jobs":{$elemMatch:{"expires_at": { "$gt": new ISODate("2013-11-09T20:47:54+02:00") }, "is_activated": true}}}});
```

Any help in how to write the API Query that results the above MongoDB query?

Here's what a document with one subdocument in the **jobs** array looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("527d00c910fedfbf7d8b4595"),
    "jobs" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("527d00c910fedfbf7d8b4584"),
            "type" : "full-time",
            "company" : "Company 30",
            "position" : "Web Developer",
            "location" : "Paris, France",
            "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
            "how_to_apply" : "Send your resume to lorem.ipsum [at] dolor.sit",
            "token" : "17ae043a3969497bce433166fcec77ee0ccb2d5d",
            "is_public" : true,
            "is_activated" : true,
            "email" : "jobnumber30@example.com",
            "expires_at" : ISODate("2013-12-08T15:18:33Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2013-11-08T15:18:33Z"),
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2013-11-08T15:18:33Z")
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Administrator",
    "slug" : "administrator"
}
```

Comment: The second query isn't actually valid

Comment: @Sammaye Could you elaborate more please. (If this is about the missing curly brace, I've added it)

Comment: $exists works as in the first query, plus you cvannot project based on that type of elematch yet

Comment: @Sammaye Hmm, Can you suggest an alternative way to do it, in MongoDB and Doctrine ?

Comment: I must be honest I have never used doctrine however, you wanna add the elemmatch to the find condition instead and then project `jobs.$:1`